# Comparing performance of SQL query vs Linq

Tags: sql, performance, linq

My question about searching queries with .NOT . I'm confused which is faster for loading and process SQL query, I have implemented SQL Server query and my query getting larger and slow of fetching data even though I'm using indexing search with SQL Server 2012.

So is there any way to make my query faster with linq?

Here is simple of my query

```
SELECT
    counting 
FROM  
    xxxxxxx 
WHERE
   (Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, '"FORM"')) 
   AND ((Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, ' "FORM"  and  "WARRANT" ' ))) 
   AND ((Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, ' "RETURN"  or  "RESPECTING"  or  "ELECTION"  or  "EXPENSES" ')))  
   OR ((Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, 'Near((FORM,WARRANT,RETURN,RESPECTING,ELECTION,EXPENSES), 1000, TRUE)' ))) 
   AND ((Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, FORM,WARRANT,RETURN,RESPECTING,ELECTION,EXPENSES)' ))) 
   AND ((Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, 'FORMSOF(THESAURUS, FORM,WARRANT,RETURN,RESPECTING,ELECTION,EXPENSES)' ))) 
ORDER BY 
   FORMTITLE ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way of improving the performance of this query with `LINQ`.

There will even be a slight overhead when using `LINQ`, but that will for sure be neglectable in this case.

`LINQ` will eventually also produce `SQL` and execute it on your database. So `LINQ` will not provide any performance benefits.

If you want to improve performance, you'll have to improve this `SQL`-statement itself.

Looking at your WHERE-clause, there are no brackets to combine any of the `AND`'s to that single `OR`. Is that on purpose? Your results will now satisfy all `AND`-conditions `OR ((Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, 'Near((FORM,WARRANT,RETURN,RESPECTING,ELECTION,EXPENSES), 1000, TRUE)' )))`

This might get you a lot more results than you are expecting.

---

**Some more on the `AND`'s and `OR`.**

Your `WHERE`-clause is now similar to:

```
(condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 AND condition5 AND condition6)
OR condition4
```

I suppose, you actually mean something like:

```
condition1 AND condition2
AND (condition3 OR condition4)
AND condition5 AND condition6
```

I don *not* say your `WHERE`-clause is wrong. I only *suspect* you need some extra brackets somewhere, to get the `WHERE`-clause you had in mind.

But before adding brackets, let's remove some to improve readability. This will do the same as yours:

```
WHERE
   Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, '"FORM"')
   AND Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, ' "FORM"  and  "WARRANT" ')
   AND Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, ' "RETURN"  or  "RESPECTING"  or  "ELECTION"  or  "EXPENSES" ')
   OR Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, 'Near((FORM,WARRANT,RETURN,RESPECTING,ELECTION,EXPENSES), 1000, TRUE)') 
   AND Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, FORM,WARRANT,RETURN,RESPECTING,ELECTION,EXPENSES)') 
   AND Contains(BOOLEANTEXT, 'FORMSOF(THESAURUS, FORM,WARRANT,RETURN,RESPECTING,ELECTION,EXPENSES)')
```

Comment: thank you for your response , i just was wondering about how to improve my query. btw do you suggest to remove OR condition caz it return more result if i use OR condition.

Comment: I added some clarification to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: so great ,,, thank you.... it is help me a lot ,,and saved much of time .. have good day